# Inviting Friends in Magic 2012 for PC

Tags: pc, steam, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012

I'm playing [Magic: The Gathering - Duels of the Planeswalkers 2012](http://store.steampowered.com/app/49470/) on PC via Steam, and I'm having a hard time connecting to friends. Whenever I create a new game, set a player slot to Private and click Invite, nothing happens. 
According to Gamespot, clicking Invite should bring up a Steam UI to let me select a friend. This is not the case, and I have to instead create a public game and hope my friend sees me and joins.

The game is running in "windowed" mode (fullscreen is turned off), and it doesn't seem to matter whether friends are online or playing the game - it still doesn't work. Everything else in the game works, including public online play.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Does your Steam show up if you hit Shift + Tab ingame? Then you can try to invite people via the friendssection. Otherwise check if you steam-ingame-overlay is enabled: Preferences -> Ingame

Comment: @Streuner Shift + Tab seems to do nothing, even in fullscreen. There are also no Ingame options under Preferences.

Comment: Huh? That's strange, because the default keys for Steam-ingame are Shift+Tab and steam implementent this ingamestuff years ago. Are you sure you checked under the preferences of steam and not the game? Just to get this clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The invites in MtG:DotP don't always pop up for your friends like they're supposed to.  However, your friends can still join your game:  In the steam friend's list, they need to click the arrow next to your name, then click **"join game."**  They can bring up the friend's list ingame by hitting `shift + tab`, or simply by minimizing the game (`alt + tab`) and opening it from Steam.

You can do the same thing to manually *invite* friends using your friend's list.

Note that joining and inviting to games both work for *most* multiplayer Steam games, not just Magic the Gathering.

Comment: True, but only if Steam Community In-Game is enabled in Steam (View > Settings > In-Game).

Comment: @Keaanu: If steam community is disabled, they can still access this by alt+tabbing out :)